# Appium: How to create google account programmatically on aws device farm devices using java before starting test run for appium-testng

Tags: appium, google-account, aws-device-farm

I want to run my automation android suite test cases on aws device farm.
Most of the script are created using gmail login.
On real time device gmail account can be configured manually ,so whenever scripts run already configured gmail account pop up for login
But in case of aws device farm ,gmail account are not configured on devices and its not possible as of now to configure gmail account on aws device farm before test run

So now I am looking for script which will run before my test run and it will configure gmail account programmatically on aws devices farm

Please make sure I am from testautomation background so please donot suggest answers in which android programming is required.My suite do not include any manifest file

Currently in my automation design I am using -> Maven(pom.xml), testng.xml (testng framework), java,POM model, eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

There is no official support for this, you could try to use UIAutomator interface to login and logout with your google account, while different Android devices may have different UI elements...

Answer (score 0):

This use case is officially supported by AWS Device Farm now. I have provided instructions and sample code for preinstalling your Google account and downloading apps from the app store (such as GMail) here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=997193&#997193

Let me know your thoughts,
Thanks,
Jon

Comment: The link shared has been archived. Please share the instructions directly