# Can I create Gmail account programmatically in Android studio?

Tags: android, gmail-api, google-account

Is possible to create Gmail account programmatically legally, not for business use , only creation.

I want to get data from My edit text and put it to any where(api) and api create account automatic or ask for capcha(Internally-no problem) and response should be gmail account and password??

I want to get data from My EditTexts and put it to any where(apis) and api to create account automatic or ask for capcha(Internally-no problem) and then create and response should be gmail account and password??

Comment: Welcome to [so]. There are several types of Google accounts including or not including Gmail, i.e. Education, Goverment, ONG, etc.?  Is this question solely about free / consumer Google accounts including Gmail (using gmail.com as the primary email domain)?

Comment: yes , ex : xyz@gmail.com , for free

Comment: Then [DalmTo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74989793/1595451) should be good enough. Anyway... there are some old questions that already have answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a Google account programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699008/can-i-create-a-google-account-programmatically)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/38051904/1595451

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google api that would allow you to programmatically create a new google user.

Tbh I don't know of any authentication server or system that would allow for it.
Just consider the number of Spam bot accounts you would end up with.